# sorting by first digit

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have array [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 20, 29, 30, 39, 40, 49, 101, 110, 119, 123]

I want to sort by keeping first digit e.g

```
1
10
101
11
110
119
12
123
2
20
29
3
30
39
4
40
49
```

is there a correct name for this sort? tried text and different methods unsure how to do this

Comment: [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should do that automatically?

Comment: .sort() does that automatically (when the input is a string instead of an integer) @evolutionxbox

Comment: @Wimanicesir nope, try it. .sort()'s default is lexicographical

Comment: (I can't find a duplicate, if it exists)

Comment: Sorry, but not starting with `.sort()` shows an egregious lack of effort.  It's the default behavior FCOL and even if it wasn't, you should start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should reorder the items like that by default.

> The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

```js
console.log(
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 20, 29, 30, 39, 40, 49, 101, 110, 119, 123].sort()
);
```

Comment: I will remove this answer if a suitable duplicate is found. I'm not hungry for rep

Comment: what if we want to do it descending?